# Idiomatic Query string parameter parsing in nodejs on AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, query-string, querystringparameter

Consider the following a nodeJS function running on AWS Lambda, serving http requests:

```js
module.exports.fetchLogLines = (event, context, callback) => {

  // Parse the 'token' param string argument
  let token = null;
  if ((event.queryStringParameters !== null) && 
      ('nextForwardToken' in event.queryStringParameters)) {
    token = event.queryStringParameters.nextForwardToken;
  }

  // Parse the 'tailf' param string argument
  let startFromHead = true;
  if ((event.queryStringParameters !== null) && 
      ('tailf' in event.queryStringParameters) &&
      (event.queryStringParameters.tailf === 'true')) {
    startFromHead = false;
  }

  // Parse the logStreamName param string argument
  const logStreamName = event.queryStringParameters.logStreamName;
  ...
```

This seems to be a cumbersome way to parse the query string arguments:

- 7 LOC for validation and parsing
- Mo obvious way to specify which arguments are required and which are optional
- No obvious way to define expected types (Integer, number, etc.) and cast
  the values
- No true value assertion - for example, `tailf` is checked for `=== 'true'`, ignoring `True`, `yes`, `1`, `on` and other texts meaning `true` in API conventions

There ought to be a library that does that.

**Is there an idiomatic way to parse query string arguments in nodeJS, define their types, and specify which arguments are required and which ones are optional?**

Comment: As you might already know, Javascript is not strongly typed. You can use typescript for this, but again in AWS lambda, this won't help. Please check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/lambda-express. It may give you an idea.

Comment: I don't need strong typing for the language, but for a well-defined query string. For instance, parsing true/false values from an argument would be very useful; an error message in case that the value was not booleanable would be divine.

Comment: I would love to know the answer to this as well, it's very cumbersome currently and it seems there must be a cleaner way.